# How to write nested-if in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm pretty new to SQL server. How to write nested-if statements with only one else clause in SQL server 2012. I want the sql code to check for the below example

```
select col1 = if(a>5 and b>3)
{ if(c>5 and d>3)
{if(e>7 and f>8) then "High"
}}
else "Low" from tbl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that more than "nested", this just are a lot of `AND`s. This can be done with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN a > 5 AND b > 3
            AND c > 5 AND d > 3
            AND e > 7 AND f > 8 THEN 'High'
            ELSE 'Low'
        END col1
FROM ...
;
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for saving my time Lamak